# Homework: Return the least element in the set greater than given element BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

So I've been stuck for hours trying to figure out this problem.

Given a randomly generated BST and using the method header:
`public E higher(E elt)`

Where `elt` is a randomly generated value within the tree's range, I need to find the least element in the set greater than `elt`.

Nodes contain left links and right links, but no parent link.

The tree in the linked image reads with the root being the leftmost node
[BST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEZPn.png).

So if `elt` is 27, then I want to return the node containing 28.

I need to run this in O(logn) time, and everything I've tried has not worked.
I'm not looking for someone to do my homework for me, but I have no clue what to do at this point.

I can provide more detail and source code if it's needed.

Edit: I'll put this here, though it's woefully inadequate. I feel as though this would be easier if I could do this recursively but I can't think of a way to do that.

```
Node n = root;
    //need to get this into a loop somehow and break out when I've found
    //the right value
    int c = myCompare(elt, ((E) n.data));
    if (c < 0) {
        n = n.left;
        //now I need to compare this against any children
    } else if (c > 0) {
        n = n.right;
        //now I need to compare this against any children
    }
    return ((E)n.data);
```

Comment: In case you want to read up more on ways this can be done, this is also referred to as the `ceiling` function. There is also `floor` which gets the highest element less than or equal to the given element.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the fundamental property of BSTs: the left child is less than the parent, the right child is greater than the parent. If you look at a sample BST you will quickly notice a few properties, and you can see why the following algorithm will work.
If the current node is less than the given value, move right, otherwise move left. If you reach a point where moving left will give you a value that is too low (or you hit a leaf) then you found the correct node. Or, in pythonic pseudo-code:

```
while (true):
   if (node.value <= elt):
      node = node.right
   else:
      if (node.left.value < elt):
         return node.value
      else:
         node = node.left
```

The pseudo-code obviously needs to check for errors, if a node is a leaf, etc., but this general algorithm will give you the expected output in the desired time complexity (assuming a balanced BST).

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to find the specified node and to get the next least node from there (if you're allowed to use helper methods).

If we say that the root node is 'n' and we know that the desired value is inside the BST, then you can traverse through it to find the node that contains the given value with something like this:

```
    public Node search(Node n, E obj)
    {
      if(obj.compareTo(n.getValue()) > 0)
      {
        return search(n.getRight(), obj);
      }
      else if(obj.compareTo(n.getValue()) < 0)
      {
        return search(n.getLeft(), obj);
      }
      else
      {
        return n;
      }
    }
```

If the objective were to retrieve the least value from a binary search tree, a simple recursive method like this would work:

```
   public Node getLeast(node n)
   {
     if(n.getLeft()==null)
     {
       return n;
     }
     return getLeast(n.getLeft());
   }
```

Using the principles of a binary search tree, we know that the least value greater than a given node is just the least node after the right child of the given node. So, we can just use this method to obtain the desired value:

```
    getLeast(search(n,elt).getRight());
```